# Web Scraping using R - non-table content/list

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to scrap the list of compound synonyms from this website:
https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/440917#section=Depositor-Supplied-Synonyms&fullscreen=true

My current code looks like this:

```
dl <- read_html("https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/440917#section=Depositor-Supplied-Synonyms&fullscreen=true")

get_synonyms <- function(x){
  
  x %>%
    html_nodes(".section-content-item") %>%
    html_text()
  
}

get_synonyms(dl)
```

I want to be able to do this for multiple compounds from PubChem so I am using a function. I am unsure what to put in the html_nodes() function based on the website's structure. The following did not work:

`section-content-item`, `section-content`, `Depositor-Supplied-Synonyms` all which seem to be classes holding the table of synonyms.

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following function will return all the synonyms for a given compound from the site, as long as you know the ID number:

```r
library(httr)
library(dplyr)

get_synonyms <- function(compound) {
  GET(paste0("https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/rest/pug_view/data/compound/",
           compound, "/JSON/?heading=Depositor+Supplied+Synonyms")) %>%
  content("parsed") %>%
  {.$Record$Section[[1]]$Section[[1]]$Section[[1]]$Information} %>%
  unlist() %>%
  as.vector()
}
```

For example, with your Limolene case:

```r
get_synonyms(440917)
#>   [1] "84"                                                         
#>   [2] "D-Limonene"                                                 
#>   [3] "5989-27-5"                                                  
#>   [4] "(R)-(+)-Limonene"                                           
#>   [5] "(+)-Limonene"                                               
#>   [6] "(D)-Limonene"                                               
#>   [7] "(+)-(4R)-Limonene"                                          
#>   [8] "(+)-carvene"                                                
#>   [9] "(4R)-Limonene"                                              
#>  [10] "D-(+)-Limonene"                                             
#>  [11] "D-Limonen"                                                  
#>  [12] "(R)-Limonene"                                               
#>  [13] "(R)-p-Mentha-1,8-diene"                                     
#>  [14] "Citrene"                                                    
#>  [15] "(+)-p-Mentha-1,8-diene"                                     
#>  [16] "(R)-4-Isopropenyl-1-methyl-1-cyclohexene"                   
#>  [17] "Limonene, D-"                                               
#>  [18] "(+)-R-Limonene"                                             
#>  [19] "Cyclohexene, 1-methyl-4-(1-methylethenyl)-, (4R)-"          
#>  [20] "d-p-Mentha-1,8-diene"                                       
#>  [21] "(+)-4-Isopropenyl-1-methylcyclohexene"                      
#>  [22] "(4R)-4-isopropenyl-1-methylcyclohexene"                     
#>  [23] "(R)-(+)-p-Mentha-1,8-diene"                                 
#>  [24] "FEMA No. 2633"                                              
#>  [25] "(R)-1-Methyl-4-(1-methylethenyl)cyclohexene"                
#>  [26] "(+)-(R)-Limonene"                                           
#>  [27] "UNII-GFD7C86Q1W"                                            
#>  [28] "r-(+)-limonene"                                             
#>  [29] "(R)-1-Methyl-4-(prop-1-en-2-yl)cyclohex-1-ene"              
#>  [30] "(4R)-1-methyl-4-prop-1-en-2-ylcyclohexene"                  
#>  [31] "MFCD00062991"                                               
#>  [32] "GFD7C86Q1W"                                                 
#>  [33] "4betaH-p-mentha-1,8-diene"                                  
#>  [34] "CHEBI:15382"                                                
#>  [35] "(+) Limonene"                                               
#>  [36] "(+)-Dipentene"                                              
#>  [37] "Carvene"                                                    
#>  [38] "Glidesafe"                                                  
#>  [39] "Glidsafe"                                                   
#>  [40] "Kautschiin"                                                 
#>  [41] "Refchole"                                                   
#>  [42] "(4R)-1-methyl-4-isopropenylcyclohex-1-ene"                  
#>  [43] "(4R)-1-methyl-4-(1-methylethenyl)cyclohexene"               
#>  [44] "Biogenic SE 374"                                            
#>  [45] "(+)-alpha-Limonene"                                         
#>  [46] "d-Limonene (natural)"                                       
#>  [47] "d-Limoneno [Spanish]"                                       
#>  [48] "Limonene, (+)-"                                             
#>  [49] "Limonene, dl-"                                              
#>  [50] "d-Limoneno"                                                 
#>  [51] "Hemo-sol"                                                   
#>  [52] "(4R)-(+)-Limonene"                                          
#>  [53] "Cyclohexene, 1-methyl-4-(1-methylethenyl)-, (R)-"           
#>  [54] "D-limonene [JAN]"                                           
#>  [55] "(4R)-4-isopropenyl-1-methyl-cyclohexene"                    
#>  [56] "Citrus stripper oil"                                        
#>  [57] "CCRIS 671"                                                  
#>  [58] "EC 7"                                                       
#>  [59] "HSDB 4186"                                                  
#>  [60] "D-1,8-p-Menthadiene"                                        
#>  [61] "NCI-C55572"                                                 
#>  [62] "EINECS 227-813-5"                                           
#>  [63] "p-Mentha-1,8-diene, (R)-(+)-"                               
#>  [64] "NSC-844"                                                    
#>  [65] "Sulfate turpentine, distilled"                              
#>  [66] "(+)-1,8-para-Menthadiene"                                   
#>  [67] "Dextro-limonene"                                            
#>  [68] "d limonene"                                                 
#>  [69] "AI3-15191"                                                  
#>  [70] "NSC-21446"                                                  
#>  [71] "Orange x"                                                   
#>  [72] "NSC-757069"                                                 
#>  [73] "1-Methyl-4-(1-methylethenyl)cyclohexene, (R)-"              
#>  [74] "EINECS 266-034-5"                                           
#>  [75] "(4R)-1-methyl-4-(prop-1-en-2-yl)cyclohex-1-ene"             
#>  [76] "Dipentene no. 122"                                          
#>  [77] "D-Limonene Reagent Grade"                                   
#>  [78] "DSSTox_CID_778"                                             
#>  [79] "EC 227-813-5"                                               
#>  [80] "DSSTox_RID_75785"                                           
#>  [81] "(+)-Limonene, stabilized with 0.03% tocopherol"             
#>  [82] "DSSTox_GSID_20778"                                          
#>  [83] "CHEMBL449062"                                               
#>  [84] "Cyclohexene, 1-methyl-4-(1-methylethenyl)-, (theta)-"       
#>  [85] "DTXSID1020778"                                              
#>  [86] "(R)-(+)-Limonene, 95%"                                      
#>  [87] "(R)-(+)-Limonene, 97%"                                      
#>  [88] "ZINC967513"                                                 
#>  [89] "CS-M3273"                                                   
#>  [90] "(R)-(+)-Limonene, >=93%"                                    
#>  [91] "Tox21_200400"                                               
#>  [92] "6458AE"                                                     
#>  [93] "AKOS015899935"                                              
#>  [94] "CCG-266134"                                                 
#>  [95] "DB08921"                                                    
#>  [96] "LMPR0102090013"                                             
#>  [97] "NSC 757069"                                                 
#>  [98] "(R)-(+)-Limonene, analytical standard"                      
#>  [99] "NCGC00248591-01"                                            
#> [100] "NCGC00248591-02"                                            
#> [101] "NCGC00257954-01"                                            
#> [102] "BS-22387"                                                   
#> [103] "CAS-5989-27-5"                                              
#> [104] "(R)-(+)-4-Isopropenyl-1-methylcyclohexene"                  
#> [105] "L0047"                                                      
#> [106] "L0105"                                                      
#> [107] "(R)-Limonene 2000 microg/mL in Acetonitrile"                
#> [108] "C06099"                                                     
#> [109] "D91245"                                                     
#> [110] "(4R)-1-Methyl-4-(prop-1-en-2-yl)cyclohexene"                
#> [111] "J-502148"                                                   
#> [112] "W-105295"                                                   
#> [113] "Q27888324"                                                  
#> [114] "(R)-(+)-Limonene, primary pharmaceutical reference standard"
#> [115] "UNII-9MC3I34447 component XMGQYMWWDOXHJM-JTQLQIEISA-N"      
#> [116] "(R)-(+)-Limonene, purum, >=96.0% (sum of enantiomers, GC)"  
#> [117] "(R)-(+)-Limonene, technical, ~90% (sum of enantiomers, GC)"
```

Or hydrochloric acid (313)

```r
get_synonyms(313)
#>   [1] "74"                                                                                                                      
#>   [2] "hydrochloric acid"                                                                                                       
#>   [3] "hydrogen chloride"                                                                                                       
#>   [4] "7647-01-0"                                                                                                               
#>   [5] "Muriatic acid"                                                                                                           
#>   [6] "Chlorohydric acid"                                                                                                       
#>   [7] "chlorane"                                                                                                                
#>   [8] "Acide chlorhydrique"                                                                                                     
#>   [9] "Chlorwasserstoff"                                                                                                        
#>  [10] "Anhydrous hydrochloric acid"                                                                                             
#>  [11] "Spirits of salt"                                                                                                         
#>  [12] "Hydrogen chloride (HCl)"                                                                                                 
#>  [13] "Chloorwaterstof"                                                                                                         
#>  [14] "Chlorowodor"                                                                                                             
#>  [15] "Acido cloridrico"                                                                                                        
#>  [16] "Muriaticum acidum"                                                                                                       
#>  [17] "Aqueous hydrogen chloride"                                                                                               
#>  [18] "chlorure d'hydrogene"                                                                                                    
#>  [19] "Hydrochloric acid gas"                                                                                                   
#>  [20] "Marine acid"                                                                                                             
#>  [21] "monohydrochloride"                                                                                                       
#>  [22] "Spirit of salt"                                                                                                          
#>  [23] "UNII-QTT17582CB"                                                                                                         
#>  [24] "NSC 77365"                                                                                                               
#>  [25] "CHEBI:17883"                                                                                                             
#>  [26] "Hydrogen chloride (acid)"                                                                                                
#>  [27] "[HCl]"                                                                                                                   
#>  [28] "HCl"                                                                                                                     
#>  [29] "QTT17582CB"                                                                                                              
#>  [30] "MFCD00011324"                                                                                                            
#>  [31] "NSC-77365"                                                                                                               
#>  [32] "E507"                                                                                                                    
#>  [33] "Bowl Cleaner"                                                                                                            
#>  [34] "4-D Bowl Sanitizer"                                                                                                      
#>  [35] "Chlorowodor [Polish]"                                                                                                    
#>  [36] "Hydrochloric Acid Solution, 1N"                                                                                          
#>  [37] "Emulsion Bowl Cleaner"                                                                                                   
#>  [38] "Caswell No. 486"                                                                                                         
#>  [39] "Hydrogenchlorid"                                                                                                         
#>  [40] "Chloorwaterstof [Dutch]"                                                                                                 
#>  [41] "o-Tolidine Dihydrochloride Solution"                                                                                     
#>  [42] "Hydrochloric acid [JAN]"                                                                                                 
#>  [43] "Chlorwasserstoff [German]"                                                                                               
#>  [44] "Hydrogen Chloride - Methanol Reagent"                                                                                    
#>  [45] "Titanium, Reference Standard Solution"                                                                                   
#>  [46] "Vanadium, Reference Standard Solution"                                                                                   
#>  [47] "Acido clorhidrico"                                                                                                       
#>  [48] "UN 1789 (solution)"                                                                                                      
#>  [49] "Hydrochloric acid, ACS reagent, 37%"                                                                                     
#>  [50] "UN 1050 (anhydrous)"                                                                                                     
#>  [51] "mono hydrochloride"                                                                                                      
#>  [52] "Acido cloridrico [Italian]"                                                                                              
#>  [53] "Platinum Cobalt Color Standard Solution"                                                                                 
#>  [54] "White Emulsion Bowl Cleaner"                                                                                             
#>  [55] "Acido clorhidrico [Spanish]"                                                                                             
#>  [56] "Varley Poly-Pak Bowl Creme"                                                                                              
#>  [57] "Acide chlorhydrique [French]"                                                                                            
#>  [58] "Hydrogen chloride (gas only)"                                                                                            
#>  [59] "Hydrochloric Acid Solution, 0.2N (N/5)"                                                                                  
#>  [60] "Hydrochloric Acid Solution, 0.5N (N/2)"                                                                                  
#>  [61] "Chlorure d'hydrogene [French]"                                                                                           
#>  [62] "Chloruro de hidrogeno"                                                                                                   
#>  [63] "HSDB 545"                                                                                                                
#>  [64] "Hydrochloric Acid Solution, 0.1N (N/10)"                                                                                 
#>  [65] "Chloruro de hidrogeno [Spanish]"                                                                                         
#>  [66] "Hygeia Creme Magic Bowl Cleaner"                                                                                         
#>  [67] "Percleen Bowl and Urinal Cleaner"                                                                                        
#>  [68] "Hydrogen chloride solution 1.0M in ethyl acetate"                                                                        
#>  [69] "EINECS 231-595-7"                                                                                                        
#>  [70] "UN1050"                                                                                                                  
#>  [71] "UN1789"                                                                                                                  
#>  [72] "UN2186"                                                                                                                  
#>  [73] "Anhydrous hydrogen chloride"                                                                                             
#>  [74] "Wuest Bowl Cleaner Super Concentrated"                                                                                   
#>  [75] "Chlorure d'hydrogene anhydre [French]"                                                                                   
#>  [76] "Cloruro de hidrogeno anhidro [Spanish]"                                                                                  
#>  [77] "EPA Pesticide Chemical Code 045901"                                                                                      
#>  [78] "Chlorure d'hydrogene anhydre"                                                                                            
#>  [79] "Cloruro de hidrogeno anhidro"                                                                                            
#>  [80] "UN 2186 (refrigerated liquefied gas)"                                                                                    
#>  [81] "chloro"                                                                                                                  
#>  [82] "chlorum"                                                                                                                 
#>  [83] "hydochloride"                                                                                                            
#>  [84] "hydrochlorie"                                                                                                            
#>  [85] "hydrochoride"                                                                                                            
#>  [86] "hydrocloride"                                                                                                            
#>  [87] "Salzsaeure"                                                                                                              
#>  [88] "Hydrochloric acid [JAN:NF]"                                                                                              
#>  [89] "chloridohydrogen"                                                                                                        
#>  [90] "hydro chloride"                                                                                                          
#>  [91] "hydro-chloride"                                                                                                          
#>  [92] "hydrogenchloride"                                                                                                        
#>  [93] "Chloro radical"                                                                                                          
#>  [94] "Soldering acid"                                                                                                          
#>  [95] "chlorhydric acid"                                                                                                        
#>  [96] "hydochloric acid"                                                                                                        
#>  [97] "hydogen chloride"                                                                                                        
#>  [98] "hydrochoric acid"                                                                                                        
#>  [99] "hydrocloric acid"                                                                                                        
#> [100] "hydrogen chlorid"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you Allan. How can I concatenate these into a continually growing dataframe? Preferably each compound a separate row/column.

Comment: Have you tried using my edits? I think that should do the trick. Just fill the numbers in.

Comment: You can't have them in a data frame because there are different numbers of synonyms for each compound, and by definition a data frame is a collection of vectors of the same length. You could use a `list` instead. Tius could be created in one go, such as `my_list <- list(limolene = get_synonyms(440917), hydrochloric = get_synonyms(313))`, or if you want to add to it, do `my_list$citric <- get_synonyms(311)`

Comment: Cheers for this. I've moved along and made a list containing all of my synonyms. One small question: How can I include the original name of each compound to this list? For example include the name at the top of the compound pages (https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/176 for acetic acid) in the list of names as well?

Answer (score 2):

The text in rendered in JavaScript, so it is easier to scrape the API as JSON and proceed by parsing it. You would need something like Selenium to scrape regularly. I tried with citric acid (311), and the same procedure works by substituting 311 for 440917 in the URL. Let me know if this works.

Additionally, I have added a procedure for a column of multiple chemicals.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(jsonlite)

data <- jsonlite::fromJSON("https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/rest/pug_view/data/compound/511/JSON/?heading=Depositor+Supplied+Synonyms")

data$Record$Section$Section[[1]]$Section[[1]]$Information[[1]][[2]][[1,1]]

#For multiple chemicals

df <- as_tibble_col(c(311, 440917, 5280450, 16129778, 1175), "IDs") %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(synonyms = list(jsonlite::fromJSON(paste("https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/rest/pug_view/data/compound/", IDs, "/JSON/?heading=Depositor+Supplied+Synonyms", sep = ""))$Record$Section$Section[[1]]$Section[[1]]$Information[[1]][[2]][[1,1]])) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Comment: Thank you for the code, it works. However the rest is unfortunate news to hear since I am unfamiliar with JavaScript, JSON, and Selenium, I was hoping this was capable in R.

Comment: Most certainly you can! My edited code makes it easy: just get all the numerical IDs in a column, and the algorithm does the rest.

Comment: This mutliple-compounds code is giving me some trouble. It is submitting a list that is 17 rows long. Also, I'd like to save it to my workspace.

Comment: Get rid of the unnest part, and you can us saveRDS(df, "file.rds") to maintain the nested structure. Or you can unnest(everything()) like earlier if need be, and save as a csv.